# Trouble formatting a text file with numpy.savetxt() and appended arrays. Python 3

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, text, append

I'm having trouble formatting a .txt document by use of numpy.savetxt, firstly I'm taking a user input filename and using it in binary append mode so I can save multiple arrays into one .txt file.

```
filename = input() 
f = open(filename, 'ab')
```

The function in the while loop (LU_sol) simply updates an array iteratively. What I would like to is append each new array to the text file as a column with each titled by the counter - which denotes time (of the calculated process not actual time).

```
while counter < fin_t:
    counter += t_step
    temp_new = LU_sol(matrix, temp_old)
    temp_new_cel = convert_temperature(temp_new, 'K', 'C') 
    print(counter,'s',temp_new_cel)
    np.savetxt(f, temp_new_cel, delimiter='\t', newline='\r\n', header = str(counter) 
    temp_old = temp_new
```

Currently I do get all the desired information into one text document, however it's written into a  single column, with the counter separating each array. (ideally i would wish to get rid of the # it writes in as well)

Is there a simple way to do this? Having worked in c my instinct is to loop over the array and print elements individually with a printed header.

Comment: `savetxt` simply iterates on the first dimension of the array, and does a formatted write: `f.write( format % tuple(row) + newline`.  `format` is derived from the `fmt` parameter and the number of columns in the array.  If the array is 2d you get multiple columns, if 1d you get one column.  Sequential calls to `savetxt` (with the same open handle) just write new lines.  It appends the `comments` parameter to the header.  If `savetxt` doesn't give you enough control, you might be better off writing your own formatted output.  For an experienced `c` programmer that should be trivial.